# Wait until fs.readFileSync is done

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my file functions.js i have two functions:

```
var email, url1

function getFile(_callback){
    email = fs.readFileSync("C:/Emails/" + items[2])
    _callback(email);    
}

function getUrl(){
    getLatestMail(function(email) {
            email.split(/\n/).forEach(function(line) {
            i++;
            if (i == 52) {
                var test = new Buffer(line, 'base64').toString(); 
                var regex = /=(.+?)"/g
                var result1 = regex.exec(test);
                url1 = result1[1].toString();
                console.log(url1);

        }

    });

getUrl()
exports.resetUrl = url1;
```

And i have a file test.js

```
var Functions = require('../pageobjects/functions.js');
var test = Functions.resetUrl;
console.log(test);
```

But it returns always undefined! The console.log in getUrl() shows the good value. It looks like that the export not is waiting until the function getURl is loaded. What is the best way to solve this? In this example i removed all the unnecessary code parts.

Comment: That is correct, `readFileSync` is asynchronous. You could either work around that, and as you haven't posted the code that calls `getFile` we would have no idea how you'd do that, or you could use the synchronous `readFile` instead.

Comment: Maybe use `readFile` instead of `readFileSync`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22863818/6429774

Comment: You have to define `resetUrl` variable in `functions.js`

Comment: @adeneo isn't it the opposite? `readFileSync` is synchronous and `readFile` is asynchronous?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen is correct: @adeneo
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

`Synchronous version of fs.readFile. Returns the contents of the file.`

Comment: @Janp95 - can you verify if you are getting the file if you just "`require(<path>)`" - there maybe an incorrect path there.

also, you can refer to using `path` and resolving the path to verify the file directory

Comment: Just like @ponury-kostek mentioned, `resetUrl` variable is not defined in any way so you refer to something that is `undefined` - do not expect it to by something different then

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen - of course it is, I got a little confused there and mixed them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the export of `functions.js` should be `exports.resetUrl = url1`

**EDIT**

You must try another approach because `getUrl` method performs asynchronous operation, so before the `url1` is set, you do the `exports.resetUrl = url1`, so it always will be undefined.

I suggest you to add some `callback` parameter to `getUrl` function that can be used in `test.js` file in order to get access to `url1` value

```
function getUrl(callback){
    getLatestMail(function(email) {
        email.split(/\n/).forEach(function(line) {
        i++;
        if (i == 52) {
            var test = new Buffer(line, 'base64').toString(); 
            var regex = /=(.+?)"/g
            var result1 = regex.exec(test);
            url1 = result1[1].toString();
            console.log(url1);
            // and here use the callback
            callback(url1);
        }
    });
});

exports.resetUrl = getUrl;
```

Then you could do in `test.js`

```
var Functions = require('../pageobjects/functions.js');
Functions.resetUrl(function(url1){
    console.log(url1);
});
```

This is only one option that first came to my mind. I hope that you get the point and understand why `url1` in your case was undefined all the time.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(url1)` just before `exports` and tell what it prints

Comment: Yes the console.log in the function getUrl returns the correct value. The console.log before the export returns undefined.

Comment: I updated the answer, check it out and tell if it helps you somehow

Comment: No sorry it didn't work, the strange thing is that i see first the undefined console.log from test.js. And then the console.log from getUrl() with the correct value...

Comment: Where did you put the `callback(url1)` part in `getUrl` function? Because I do not see any reason why it should not work

Comment: `function getUrl(callback){
        getFile(function(email) {

        email.split(/\n/).forEach(function(line) {
                url1 = result1[1].toString();                                                            console.log(url1);
            }

        });        
       
    });

    callback(resetUrl);
};`

Comment: Take a look at updated answer, the `callback` is used in `getUrl` method in the `if (i == 52)` statement, after computations and `console.log`