# TypeError: "FunctionName" is not a function during async and await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to javascript and trying to understand Async and Await.
This is the code which I have written which tries to read from a file and if the file is not found it rejects.

```
async function getFileAsString(path) {
    if (!path) {
        throw "you need to give a path!"
    }

    const fileContent = await fileCheck(path);
    console.log(fileContent)
}

var fileCheck = function(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (fs.readFileAsync(path, "utf-8")) {
            resolve("File found!")
        } else {
            reject("File not found!!")
        }
    })
}
```

I am getting a error saying "TypeError: fileCheck is not a function during async and await. I cant figure out the reason. Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: And `fileCheck` is used like...

Comment: fonction assignments declarations are not hoisted to the top of the scope, hence the undefined.

Comment: fileCheck is used to check whether the path exists or not. If it does it resolves else it rejects

Comment: `var fileCheck = function` should be `async function fileCheck` maybe?

Comment: Pro tip: never use a function statement when not neccessary... And what should that `if` statement do?

Comment: @hackerman nope that wont improve anything (i sometimes use that to document APIs better, but actually that just sets up a nested Promise that is then flattened)

Comment: if is used to read the file.

Comment: At first: there is no `readFileAsync`, have a look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). And why fo you think that you can put async code in an if statement and get a meaningful result? A promise is an object abd therefore always truthy, your fileCheck will resolve long before the file is actually checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1)

```
 fs.readFileAsync(path, "utf-8")
```

does not exist. Just omit the `Async`. `readFile` is async by default.

2)

```
 if(fs.readFile(path, "utf-8"))
```

As noticed above, `readFile` is async, that means that it does not return anything (= `undefined`) but rather calls the passed callback somewhen. So you either use the sync version:

```
 try {
   fs.readFileSync(path, "utf-8")
   // ... All fine
 } catch(error){
   // File corrupted / not existing
 }
```

or you check in the callback:

```
 fs.readFile(path, "utf-8", function callback(error, data){
   if(error) /*...*/;
 });
```

3) Using the function expression as such:

`var checkFile = function(){}`

is a bad idea as it introduces hoisting problems and so on.

---

```
 function checkFile(path){
   return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.readFile(path, "utf-8", function callback(err, data){
         err ? rej(err) : res(data);
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't abbreviate `resolve()` / `reject()`, but otherwise +1

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the callback-style asynchronous function `fs.readFile()` using [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
var readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function getFileAsString(path) {
    // `readFile()` will throw proper error if `path` is invalid
    const fileContent = await readFile(path, 'utf-8')
    console.log(fileContent)
    return fileContent
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was doing this the other day, there are a couple things that are going wrong above. Try something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class FileManager {
  async getFileAsString(path) {
    if (!path) {
        throw "you need to give a path!"
    }

    const fileContent = await this.fileCheck(path);
    console.log(fileContent)
  }

  fileCheck(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      fs.readFile(path,'utf8',(err, result) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(result);
      });
    })
  }
}

// Example usage
const fileManager = new FileManager();
fileManager.getFileAsString('./release.js');
```

It is a little bit of extra code, but putting it in a class prevents the hoisting issues mentioned above. Also I noticed last week when I was doing this, async / await was behaving weirdly when not used with a class, not sure what that was about...

### [EDIT]

Also there is a readFileSync method that already does this, have a look at this thread:

[Difference between readFile and readFileSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604866/difference-between-readfile-and-readfilesync)

Comment: Dont we define the fileCheck?

Comment: 1) `async / await` does not behave weirdly when used outside of a class 2) this code will still not work in any way there are too many errors in it

Comment: @JonasW. such as?

Comment: @Asleepace maybe you should test your solution before posting it, then you'd know...

Comment: @asleepace its actually not our job to fix your answer.

Comment: @JonasW. not sure what your MO is, but if I saw a tiny missing syntactic mistake here or there I would point it out. You make it sound as if there are just millions of bugs just leaping out of this code...