# Display base64 image HTML from source

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Is it possible to display a base64 image in html from a textfile containing the information?
The only way I know is to paste the whole content in html.

**for instance:**

```
<div>
<p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Maybe I have to use JS?

Comment: depending on your environment, there might be different techniques to do it. So what else do you use? or just plain html?

Comment: The idea is to insert the image dynamically? If so You could use JS: make an AJAX call (GET .txt file) and then insert the image dynamically with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
'use strict';

 const fs = require('fs');

 let buff = fs.readFileSync('test-image.png');  
 let base64data = buff.toString('base64');

 console.log('Image converted to base 64 is:\n\n' + base64data);
```

Have you ever use NodeJs? If you don't know you have to install it. (https://nodejs.org/it/)
You can put where you want the output string also inside the attribute src of the tag img.

Comment: You should use `fs.readFile` instead (in most cases). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605734/6624953) briefly explains why.