# Electron / node - Snipppets using require and readFile makes javascript fail

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, electron

I use Electron which uses NodeJS. I started with a single very long HTML file. Now I want to split it up, similar to PHP `require`. I managed to do so with `require` and `readFile`.

However after using this approach my javascript stopped working. My guess is that my whole approach is wrong.

### Inline script

```js
const fs = require('fs');
require('./assets/js/snippets.js');
```

### snippets.js

```js
function snippet(name) {
  fs.readFile('snippets/' + name + '.html', function (err, data) {
    document.querySelector('[snippet-' + name + ']').innerHTML = data.toString();
  });
}

snippet('header');
snippet('post');
snippet('footer);
```

What is the correct way to do this? Can I use the built in functions or do I need an exernal library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readFileSync`can be used instead of `readFile`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110224/148496