# Javascript readdirSync - count number of strings outside function

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, file-io, promise

I'm trying to write a script that allows me to search for a string in a number of folders and then return the output. I've managed to find the readdirSync function which does what I want, however I am unable to print out the total number of strings found because it is ran before the function is complete. Please see example below.

```
var totalNumberOfStringFound = 0;

function numberofStringsInFolder(dir, search) {
var fs = require('fs');
var results = [];
var searchTerm = search;

fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (file) {
file = dir + '/' + file;
var stat = fs.statSync(file);

if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
  results = results.concat(numberOfTagsInFolder(file));
} else {
  fs.readFile(file, bar);
  function bar(err, data) {
    err ? Function('error', 'throw error')(err) : (fileContent = data.toString('utf8'));
    var count = (fileContent.match(new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi')) || []).length;
    totalNumberOfStringFound = totalNumberOfStringFound + count;
    console.log('NUMBER OF STRINGS FOUND: ' + totalNumberOfStringFound);
  }
  // Holds the list of files found
  results.push(file);
}
});
  console.log("totalNumberOfStringFound: " + totalNumberOfStringFound);
  return results;
}

 numberofStringsInFolder('./folder', 'HELLO');
```

Output

```
 totalNumberOfStringFound: 0
 NUMBER OF STRINGS FOUND: 2
 NUMBER OF STRINGS FOUND: 3
```

The output (totalNumberOfStringFound) should be 3, but because totalNumberOfStringFound is called before the function has finished, it is showing as 0. I've looked online and some people use the timeout function, but I don't want to use that because I don't know how long it will take to complete. I would really appreciate it if someone can help. Thank you

Comment: `fs.readFile(file, bar);` this is async call with `bar` being called as a callback. Try changing your code to use `fs.readFileSync`

Comment: @Anton - Thanks that worked! Looked into it in more detail and found out how it's used. If anyone else has this problem check out this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604866/difference-between-readfile-and-readfilesync

Comment: Good that it worked for you. By the way, can you close the question without the accepted answer?