# Push array of objects in JSON file to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to store JSON file content into a Javascript array, but I am getting an empty array as result.

```
const displayTask = () => {
  let text = [];
  fs.readFile(fileConfig, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const content = JSON.parse(data);
    for (let task in content) {
      text.push(task);
    }
  });
  console.log(text);
};
```

output -> []

The type of JSON data is:
[image]

Thanks to everyone, found the correct solution:

```
const displayTask = async() => {
return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileConfig, (err, data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        text = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(text);
        resolve();
    })
})
```

};

Comment: Your console is getting printed before readFile is complete. Hence you are seeing the output as empty. You have to process it in your readFile callback

Comment: try this:

const displayTask = async () => {
   try {
        const content = await fs.promises.readFile(fileConfig, 'uts-8')
  return [JSON.parse(content)]
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
  }
};

Comment: This will point you in the right directioin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604866/difference-between-readfile-and-readfilesync