# Return URL of locally stored image [Node JS API]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I'm create an API that receive base64 string, convert it to image [label.jpeg], then return URL of the image. Now I'm stuck at how to create URL of local image so that it can be accessed publicly.

Below is my code, the goal is return URL address of the 'label.jpeg' when the API is called.

```js
// Post base64 string
app.post('/post-base64', (req, res) => {

    // Captured img [base64 string]
    let strBase64 = req.body
    console.log(strBase64)

    // Convert base64 --> img.jpeg
    let buffer = Buffer.from(strBase64, 'base64')
    console.log(buffer)

    // Write base64 to file
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('label.txt')
    writeStream.write(buffer, 'base64')


    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('WROTE ALL!')
    })

    writeStream.end()

    // Save img as 'label.jpeg'
    fs.writeFileSync('label.jpeg', buffer)

    res.send({
        // TOD0: Return label.jpeg link
    })
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the uploaded image in a "public" folder that you serve [statically](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) through `express.static`. So for example:

```
// add this to your app.js
app.use(express.static('public'))

// store uploaded image in the public folder
app.post(..) => {
   // ... note that you should probably switch
   // to the non-blocking version e.g. fs.promises.writeFile(...)
   fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '../public/name-of-img.jpeg', buffer)
})
```

Express will now take care of serving the file, so the URL for the image will simply be `http://yourhostname/name-of-img.jpeg`

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync` is bad here, you block the whole eventloop when a upload is running.

Comment: Yes sure, but it's not directly related to the OP's question. I'll leave a hint in the comment though ;)

Comment: Actually I do have this `app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`  above my code. So, URL of the img should be `http://localhost:2000/static/label.jpeg` right? But I couldn't get the img, got 404 err.   Could you explain more on the non-blocking ver. though.

Comment: The path looks ok, but are you using the correct relative path to the public folder (e.g. `../public/<filename>`) when storing the file? Regarding why you should not use the synchronous version... this has been asked many times, see this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604866/difference-between-readfile-and-readfilesync